# How to secure static site in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, security, authentication, static

I have unique requirement to secure static site (html pages) in laravel by not creating views for each html page. 
We have already configured SSO in laravel and want to show the static site to only authenticated SSO users. The static site is too much big and it will take alot of time by creating controllers and views for all static pages.

Experts please suggest if there is any possible solution for above requirements

Answer (score 1):

While I certainly wouldn't recommend this way of doing things, it should be theoretically possible.  I have provided an oversimplified example — of course, you would need to set up additional methods to handle anything other than HTML.

**EDIT:** It's not clear how your SSO is set up since you didn't provide any code, but you would need to use a middleware group such as `auth` to secure the route.  Also, `path/to/static_html` should not be publicly visible.

**web.php**

```php
// auth middleware group
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

   // catch-all route - place at end of file
   Route::any('{path?}', 'PageController@handle')->where('path', '.*');
});
```

**PageController.php**

```php
class PageController extends BaseController
{
    public function handle($path = 'index.html')
    {
        $html = file_get_contents(base_path('path/to/static_html/'.$path));

        return view('default',compact('html'));
    }
}
```

**default.blade.php**

```php
{!! $html !!}
```